# Fibonacci Quadratic Residue

Tags: modular-arithmetic, fibonacci-numbers, quadratics

After some research I have came up with a conjecture on Fibonacci quadratic residue:

> $F(x)^2 mod F(y)$ =
>
> { if y is even: $(F(|x-y|)^2$  }
>
> { if y is odd:  $-(F(|x-y|)^2$ }
>
> for values where $|x-y| \le \frac{y+1}{2}$

Where F(n) = the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number

Questions:

> 1. Does this apply for all Fibonacci numbers (all y values), and if so, what is the proof?
> 2. And how can this be extended for values where $|x-y| \gt \frac{y+1}{2}$

I have tested this up to around F10 and the pattern seems to be stable

Examples:

1. For F8:

F8 = 21 so We are looking for numbers $F(n)^2$ mod 21 Here is the sequence starting from n = 0:

```
(0,1,1,4,9,4,1,1,0,1,1,4,9,4...)
                 A
```

2. now F9 = 34 so the sequence $F(n)^2$ mod 34 from n=0 is

`(0,1,1,4,-25,-9,-4,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-4,-9,-25,4,1,1,0,1,4,9...)
                          A`

Point A marks where x = y

Comment: Are you using the convention $F_0=F_1=1$ or the convention $F_1=F_2=1$?  (I suppose I could figure it out by running through a couple of examples, but I'm lazy.  I'd like it if *you'd* show us a couple of examples of what you mean.)

Comment: I just answered your question on Academia.SE--I am pretty angry that it was merged like that. I thought it was most appropriate for meta, but it's a shame it was merged the way it was. I was not a member of Academia.SE until just now because of my answering. Cannot comment because < 50 rep. Not happy with the party responsible for that merger. I'g guessing it was @mixedmath who did it.